# AWS Lambda handler's Java output streams - don't need to be closed after writing?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm pretty new to AWS Lambda, and am using Input and Output streams for my Lambda request handler (in Java). (Following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html)

I was recently asked by a teammate if I need to close the output stream after writing my output bytes to it. I understand that for Java, closing streams after use is general best practice, but is it completely unnecessary in the case of the output stream of a Lambda due to the way AWS Lambdas work? Is this just something Lambdas clean up automatically or are there any potential risks to not explicitly closing them?

I have tried to look for documentation about it, but I haven't found anything specific and I'd like a better answer to my teammate than "all the examples don't close the output streams" or "I'm guessing it just has to do with how Lambda handles invocations".

Comment: In practice, you should **close any stream you open**. Here however, _you_ are not the one opening them, they are passed into your handler. I would expect the caller to properly close them. If you open any additional streams, those you should properly close.

Comment: @MattClark perfect. Thanks!